# accessing files from another partition

Tags: partitioning, 13.10, windows-7

I've been using Windows for some time and I've just installed Ubuntu and would like to make available some of the media files (mostly my iTunes songs and movies) to my Ubuntu partition.  My question is, is there an easy way to just copy them over in Ubuntu (I noticed that the other partition is available through a mount in /media)?

I tried ~$sudo cp /Movies /home/jesse/
And I got
omitted /Movies

Is there any easy way to do this, or do I have to shimmy everything in my Dropbox?

Comment: You could simply use the file manager to do that. And by `/Movies`, I suppose you meant `/media/YOUR_USERNAME/PARTITION_NAME`, right? That's where other storage devices are usually mounted in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment it looks like it is already mounted.

cp need a -R if you are going to recursively go though directories.

Try the command

```
cp -R /media/<username>/<NTFS-Partition>/Movies /home/jesse/
```

Comment: Sudo is a bad idea here. It will make all copies in the user's home owned by root with loss of write access.